# Menu Drawer is not working when swipe left to right to show it

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using react-native-router-flux to show a drawer menu but the hamburguer menu is just working when I click it. But when I try to swipe from left to right the menu is not showing, it  also is not get hide when I click outside of menu.

this is my route:

```
export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <Scene>
                <Drawer
                    hideNavBar
                    key="drawerMenu"
                    contentComponent={SideBar}
                    drawerWidth={250}
                    drawerPosition="right"
                >
                    <Scene
                        key="profileScreen"
                        component={Home}

                    />

                </Drawer>
            </Scene>

        </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

And my home page is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Home = () => {

  const goToAbout = () => {
     Actions.about()
  }
  return (
     <TouchableOpacity style = {{ margin: 128 }} onPress = {goToAbout}>
        <Text>This is HOME!</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
  )
 }
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,    
  },
});

export default Home;
```

My package json is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0"
  },
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

in the index.js of your project:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(App));
```

Comment: Awsome. this is work like a charm. how did you get it?